# Error in locking authority file for parallelisation with qmake

Tags: r, cluster-computing, qmake, xauth

I work with **Rscript** on a cluster. **qmake** (a specialized version of GNU-make for the cluster) is used to parallelize jobs on several nodes. But Rscript seems to need to write a **Xauthority** file and it creates an error when every nodes work in the same time. In this way, my makefile-bases pipeline  stops after the first group of parallelized tasks and don't start the next group of tasks. But the results of the first group are ok.

I'm also invoking usr/bin/xvfb-run ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) when runnning RScript.

I've already changed the ssh-config (FORWARD X11 yes) but the problem persists. 
I also tried to change the name of Xauthority file for each job but it didn't work (option -f in Rscript).

Here is the error which appear at the beginning of the process

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file .Xauthority
```

Here is the error which appears before the process stops :

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 171: kill: (44402) - No such process
qmake: *** [Data/Median/median_B00FTXC.tmp] Error 1
```